# How can I opt the user to delete all files in a folder (but no subdirectories)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file-io

I've got a folder path. The folder contains a lot of files as well as some subfolders. I'd like to let the user delete the files (but not the folders) using the standard windows dialog.

I'm currently using this code, which deletes the whole folder.

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory (
    path,
    UIOption.AllDialogs,
    RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin,
    UICancelOption.DoNothing);
```

I'm aware I could enumerate all files and prompt the user for each file, but that's not practical at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just write a function for this specific task?

```
public static void DeleteFilesInFolder()
        {
            using(var dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                if(dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    var folderPath = dlg.SelectedPath;
                    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
                    var files =dir.GetFiles();
                    foreach (var f in files)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        f.Delete();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {
                        //handle this error
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
```

ah ok, just a suggestion..

then have a look at this:

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/RecycleBin2.aspx

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SHFILEOPSTRUCT
{
    public IntPtr hwnd;
    public uint wFunc;
    public string pFrom;
    public string pTo;
    public ushort fFlags;
    public int fAnyOperationsAborted;
    public IntPtr hNameMappings;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string lpszProgressTitle; 
}

private const int FO_DELETE = 0x0003;
private const int FOF_SILENT = 0x0004;
private const int FOF_ALLOWUNDO = 0x0040;
private const int FOF_NOCONFIRMATION = 0x0010;
private const int FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING = 0x4000;

[DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
static extern int SHFileOperation([In] ref SHFILEOPSTRUCT lpFileOp);
```

used like this to delete all files matching the `*.*` pattern in a folder:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT operation = new SHFILEOPSTRUCT();
operation.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
operation.pFrom = @"c:\Recycle\*.*" + "\0\0";
operation.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO;
int result = SHFileOperation(ref operation);
```

Comment: I already know the path, no need to have the user select it again. `File.Delete()` does not delete to the recycle bin. Also, I'd like to prompt the user to accept "deleting 497 files?" by using the standard windows dialog.

Comment: Just add a second YesNo dialogbox with a "Are you sure you want to delete " + dir.GetFiles().Count + "?" message after you select your directory.

Comment: Carra: I really would prefer to use built-in functionality.

Comment: It does not yet exactly what I want it to, but it's a very good starting point. Thanks! Sadly SO won't let me upvote your answer :(

Answer (score 1):

Visual Basic uses the [SHFileOperation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28VS.85%29.aspx) API function to display the dialog.  I think you can call it yourself and customize it the way you want by specifying the FOF_FILESONLY flag for the [SHFILEOPSTRUCT.fFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759795%28VS.85%29.aspx) member.  The P/Invoke is gritty, visit pinvoke.net for the declarations.

Comment: here's an SHFileOperation to copy files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722907/vb-filesystem-copy-how-to-get-new-name-of-renamed-file/12373552#12373552

you could change the FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM flags to someting like FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING and FOF_NORECURSION or FOF_FILESONLY. You should get the confirm dialog as long as you don't use FOF_NOERRORUI