# VB FileSystem.Copy - how to get new name of renamed file

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, filenames

I'm using this function to copy a file into a program directory:

```
new Computer().FileSystem.CopyFile(source,
                                   destination,
                                   UIOption.AllDialogs, 
                                   UICancelOption.ThrowException);
```

If a file is there with the same name, the user is shown the regular windows dialog that asks to replace, cancel or copy with a new name.

**Is there anyway to return the new name for that file?**

Comment: Why don't you make sure file doesn't already exist?

Comment: it is possible they are two different files with the same name. I could do all the checking and ask about rename or overwrite myself, but that defeats the purpose of using this function

Comment: @mobiletim I think there is no way to get what you want either with this function or Windows API functions such as SHCopyFile or other relevant APIs since all of them (at least the ones I know, only return an error code or a boolean showing that if the copy operation was successful), you may want to ask the user about and take care of rename and overwrite your self.

Comment: The underlying Windows API function (SHFileOperation) is capable of returning this information through the SHFILEOPSTRUCT.hNameMappings member.  The pinvoke you'll need is gritty.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [code](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1236265012) which does what you are after, my interpretation is in C# though...

```
public class Win32ApiUtils
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public FO_Func WFunc;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string PFrom;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pTO;
        public ushort fFlags;
        public bool FAnyOperationsAborted;
        public IntPtr HNameMappings;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string LpszProgressTitle;

    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private struct SHNAMEMAPPING
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string PszOldPath;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string PszNewPath;
        public int CchOldPath;
        public int CchNewPath;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct HANDLETOMAPPINGS
    {
        public uint UNumberOfMappings;
        public IntPtr LpSHNameMapping;
    }

    [DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int SHFileOperation(ref SHFILEOPSTRUCT LpFileOp);

    [DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
    private static extern void SHFreeNameMappings(SHNAMEMAPPING IntPtr);

    public static int CopyFiles()
    {
        // set up our file operation structure
        SHFILEOPSTRUCT sh;
        sh.hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        sh.WFunc = FO_Func.FO_COPY;

        sh.PFrom = @"C:\temp\f1\a.txt" + Constants.vbNullChar + @"C:\temp\f1\b.txt" + Constants.vbNullChar +
                   Constants.vbNullChar;

        sh.fFlags = (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_ALLOWUNDO
                    | (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_MULTIDESTFILES
                    | (ushort)FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM.FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE;

        sh.FAnyOperationsAborted = false;
        sh.HNameMappings = IntPtr.Zero;
        sh.LpszProgressTitle = null;

        sh.pTO = @"C:\temp\a.txt" + Constants.vbNullChar + @"C:\temp\b.txt" + Constants.vbNullChar +
                 Constants.vbNullChar;

        int ret = SHFileOperation(ref sh);

        if (sh.HNameMappings != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // Copy from Sh.HNameMappings to HANDLETOMAPPINGS 
            HANDLETOMAPPINGS mappings =
                (HANDLETOMAPPINGS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(sh.HNameMappings, typeof(HANDLETOMAPPINGS));

            // initialize the pointer for reading at the position of the mappings.LpSHNameMapping 
            IntPtr ptr = mappings.LpSHNameMapping;

            for (int I = 0; I < (int)mappings.UNumberOfMappings; I++)
            {
                // read from the pointer
                // copying to SHNAMEMAPPING
                SHNAMEMAPPING mapping = (SHNAMEMAPPING)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(SHNAMEMAPPING));

                // create file info from mapping
                // something we can get at
                FileInfo fileNew = new FileInfo(mapping.PszNewPath);

                Console.WriteLine("new file name: {0}", fileNew.Name);

                // advance by the size of the structure to the next SHNAMEMAPPING
                ptr = new IntPtr(ptr.ToInt32() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SHNAMEMAPPING)));
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum FILEOP_FLAGS_ENUM : ushort
    {
        FOF_MULTIDESTFILES = 0x0001,
        FOF_CONFIRMMOUSE = 0x0002,
        FOF_SILENT = 0x0004, // don't create progress/report
        FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION = 0x0008,
        FOF_NOCONFIRMATION = 0x0010, // Don't prompt the user.
        FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE = 0x0020, // Fill in SHFILEOPSTRUCT.hNameMappings
        // Must be freed using SHFreeNameMappings
        FOF_ALLOWUNDO = 0x0040,
        FOF_FILESONLY = 0x0080, // on *.*, do only files
        FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS = 0x0100, // means don't show names of files
        FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR = 0x0200, // don't confirm making any needed dirs
        FOF_NOERRORUI = 0x0400, // don't put up error UI
        FOF_NOCOPYSECURITYATTRIBS = 0x0800, // dont copy NT file Security Attributes
        FOF_NORECURSION = 0x1000, // don't recurse into directories.
        FOF_NO_CONNECTED_ELEMENTS = 0x2000, // don't operate on connected elements.
        FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING = 0x4000,
        // during delete operation, warn if nuking instead of recycling (partially overrides FOF_NOCONFIRMATION)
        FOF_NORECURSEREPARSE = 0x8000, // treat reparse points as objects, not containers
    }

    public enum FO_Func : uint
    {
        FO_MOVE = 0x0001,
        FO_COPY = 0x0002,
        FO_DELETE = 0x0003,
        FO_RENAME = 0x0004,
    }


}
```

}